# Does heat affect the macronutrient breakdown of cooking fats?

Tags: food, nutrition-information, food-preparation

I keep a close watch on the nutritional content of my food for weight-control purposes, and I don't know how to account for the fats I use when cooking. For example, I've been accounting for butter as if in raw form based on the information here: http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/dairy-and-egg-products/133/2. However, I have a feeling that this may not a correct measure, as the heat may affect its composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cooking (whether baking, frying, grilling, or using a microwave) has a nominal effect on the nutritional value of foods. Using the uncooked data for calculating the post frying impact is fine.

Comment: * with the caveat that you don't take cooking oils past their smoke point, when the chemical composition does change (for the worse). In the case of butter, however, I think its a non-issue as butter holds up to very high heat.